# Header is not staying in the absolute center of its container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a student attempting to learn how to create websites.

My header ("This Will Be The Day") appears centered, however when I change the resolution and size of the page, it doesn't stay centered relative to the content below it. Below I have the CSS and HTML content of my page.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #eee;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Geneva, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
}

h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 1em;
}

.container {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.banner {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2em;
  background-color: #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}

.nav {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}

.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 75%;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.content {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  margin: 0 0 0 10%;
}

.footer {
  clear: both;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 2em;
  text-align: right;
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
}

ol {
  float: left;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  float: left;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

iframe {
  float: left;
  align: center;
  padding-left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="banner">
    <h1>RWBY Lyrics</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <button class="accordion">Volume One</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <a href="RWBYThisWillBeTheDay.html">This Will Be The Day</a>
    </div><button class="accordion">Volume Two</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Volume Two Songs Here</p>
    </div><button class="accordion">Volume Three</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Volume Three Songs Here</p>
    </div><button class="accordion">Volume Four</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Volume Four Songs Here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
          this.classList.toggle("active");
          var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
          if (panel.style.display === "block") {
              panel.style.display = "none";
          } else {
              panel.style.display = "block";
          }
      });
    }
  </script>
  <div class="content">
    <h2>This Will Be The Day</h2>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      They see you as small and helpless;
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      They see you as just a child.
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      Surprise when they find out that a warrior will soon run wild.
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      Prepare for your greatest moments;
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      Prepare for your finest hour.
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      The dream that you've always dreamed is suddenly about to flower.
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      We are lightning,
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      Straying from the thunder,
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      Miracles of ancient wonder.
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      This will be the day we've waited for.
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      This will be the day we open up the door.
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      I don't wanna hear your absolution;
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      Hope you're ready for a revolution.
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      Welcome to a world of new solutions.
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      Welcome to a world of bloody evolution.
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      In time, your heart will open minds,
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      A story will be told,
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      And victory is in a simple soul
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      Your world needs a great defender.
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      Your world's in the way of harm.
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      You want a romantic life; a fairytale that's full of charm.
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      Beware that the light is fading;
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      Beware if the dark returns.
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      This world's unforgiving; even brilliant lights will cease to burn.
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      Legends scatter.
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      Day and night will sever.
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      Hope and peace are lost forever.
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      This will be the day we've waited for...
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      We are lightning...
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      Welcome to a world of new solutions...
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      This will be the day we've waited for.
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      This will be the day we open up the door.
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      I don't wanna hear your absolution;
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      Hope you're ready for a revolution.
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      Welcome to a world of new solutions.
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      Welcome to a world of bloody evolution.
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      In time, your heart will open minds,
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      A story will be told,
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2em">
      And victory is in a simple soul
    </div><iframe align="center" allowfullscreen frameborder="0" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Tb1_93M8SXA?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" width="560"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    I highly recommend taking a look at the RWBY Wiki located at <a href="rwby.wikia.com">rwby.wikia.com</a> for more information.
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that I'm using the `h2` tag in order to put my header on the page, so it most likely lies in that CSS.

Comment: h1 {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

Comment: "header of the page" you're talking about "This Will be The Day" right? Looking at your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the header, it's because you're using `ol`s and `ul`s inappropriately -- they place an indentation on the elements inside them.

Change your html from

```
<h2>
This Will Be The Day
</h2>
<ol>They see you as small and helpless;</ol>
<ol>They see you as just a child.</ol>
<ul>Surprise when they find out that a warrior will soon run wild.   </ul>
```

to

```
<h2>
This Will Be The Day
</h2>
<p class="poem">
They see you as small and helpless;<br>
They see you as just a child.<br>
Surprise when they find out that a warrior will soon run wild.<br>
</p>
```

and add this to your CSS

```
p.poem {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: you can even remove the styles for `ol` and `ul` elements

Comment: @flauto.2 please consider accepting my answer if it solved your problem. thanks

Comment: That helps a lot! I'll be implementing it into the site right now. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

1. The `ul` and `ol` are unnecessary, you can omit those. Put the whole lyrics in a paragraph `p`, then put `<br>` at the end of each line to break to new line.
2. If you want the heading (This Will Be The Day) `h2` and the lyrics `p` go together when you resize the window, you should give them same style. For example:

   ```
   h2 {
   margin: 2em;
   text-align: left;
   padding: auto;
   }

   p {
   margin: 2em;
   text-align: left;
   padding: auto;
   }
   ```

Here's the result:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #eee;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Geneva, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
}

h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin: 2em;
  text-align: left;
  padding: auto;

}

p {
  margin: 2em;
  text-align: left;
  padding: auto;
}

.container {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.banner {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2em;
  background-color: #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}

.nav {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}

.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 75%;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.content {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  margin: 0 0 0 10%;
}

.footer {
  clear: both;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 2em;
  text-align: right;
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
}
iframe {
 float: middle;
  margin: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: auto;
}
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="banner">
    <h1>RWBY Lyrics</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <button class="accordion">Volume One</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <a href="RWBYThisWillBeTheDay.html">This Will Be The Day</a>
    </div><button class="accordion">Volume Two</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Volume Two Songs Here</p>
    </div><button class="accordion">Volume Three</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Volume Three Songs Here</p>
    </div><button class="accordion">Volume Four</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Volume Four Songs Here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
          this.classList.toggle("active");
          var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
          if (panel.style.display === "block") {
              panel.style.display = "none";
          } else {
              panel.style.display = "block";
          }
      });
    }
  </script>
  <div class="content">
    <h2>This Will Be The Day</h2>
    <p>
    They see you as small and helpless; <br>
They see you as just a child.<br>
Surprise when they find out that a warrior will soon run wild.<br>
Prepare for your greatest moments;<br>
Prepare for your finest hour.<br>
The dream that you've always dreamed is suddenly about to flower.<br>
We are lightning,<br>
Straying from the thunder,<br>
Miracles of ancient wonder.<br>
This will be the day we've waited for.<br>
This will be the day we open up the door.<br>
I don't wanna hear your absolution;<br>
Hope you're ready for a revolution.<br>
Welcome to a world of new solutions.<br>
Welcome to a world of bloody evolution.<br>
In time, your heart will open minds,<br>
A story will be told,<br>
And victory is in a simple soul<br>
Your world needs a great defender<br>
Your world's in the way of harm.<br>
You want a romantic life; a fairytale that's full of charm.<br>
Beware that the light is fading;<br>
Beware if the dark returns.<br>
This world's unforgiving; even brilliant lights will cease to burn.<br>
Legends scatter.<br>
Day and night will sever.<br>
Hope and peace are lost forever.<br>
This will be the day we've waited for...<br>
We are lightning...<br>
Welcome to a world of new solutions...<br>
This will be the day we've waited for.<br>
This will be the day we open up the door.<br>
I don't wanna hear your absolution;<br>
Hope you're ready for a revolution.<br>
Welcome to a world of new solutions.<br>
Welcome to a world of bloody evolution.<br>
In time, your heart will open minds,<br>
A story will be told,<br>
And victory is in a simple soul
</p>
<iframe align="center" allowfullscreen frameborder="0" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Tb1_93M8SXA?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" width="560"></iframe>
</div>
  <div class="footer">
    I highly recommend taking a look at the RWBY Wiki located at <a href="rwby.wikia.com">rwby.wikia.com</a> for more information.
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```